# How will EAP start listening to server port in Camel Context XML?

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse, karaf, cxfrs

OK, this might be a stupid question, 
How the will EAP/ Karaf listen to **8484**. Do I need to configure all ports that I'm use in Server Configuration.

```
<cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="http://localhost:8484/customerservice">
```

Answer (score 1):

JBoss Fuse (Karaf) will start an instance of Jetty listening to port 8484, no need to configure it anywhere.
Different bundles will automatically re-use that instance, if listening on the same port. Jetty will be stopped after you stop the bundle.
I can't say for EAP.

I don't remember at the moment, you may or may not need to install the following features:

```
features:install camel-http
features:install camel-jetty
```